# How to create solid group SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to group SQL columns. Useful usage is `group by`. But it is not working. My target data is below. Second picture is my desired table. How do I create second result? How do I write the SQL code? Below is only a sample; don't focus on `id`, `Name`, `SurName` etc. The important things are `Value` and `Group`.

[image]

My desired result: 
[image]

Below my undesired result:  Group is string. if al column X0digitdigitdigit format. every thing is ok via order by. but group A0123,A0045, A0003 etc 
[image]

Comment: which columns are being aggregated ? If there is nothing to aggregate then how can you `group by`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
    FROM tbl
ORDER BY [group], value;
```

Comment: Edit the question and show your "not working" code. What you have tried.

Comment: Group is string. if al column X0digitdigitdigit format. every thing is ok via order by. but group A0123,A0045, A0003 etc. look my question 3th picture please

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding GROUP BY.

GROUP BY returns 1 result row per group. That means you can't return individual results in your result rows, only the group itself and aggregates (e.g. COUNT, SUM, MAX) calculated on the group.

ORDER BY is what you want here.